# javascript: What is a NOT NOT? (!! operator )

Tags: javascript, operators, comparison-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the !! operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-operator-in-javascript)

What is a not not in javascript I have seen this a few times :)

```
function foo(){
    return !!(window.history);
}
```

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-operator-in-javascript

Comment: It's a duplicate, but that duplicate question barely mentions why it's used. In your case, it's [the bottom answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-operator-in-javascript/4339463#4339463): it's an idiom to check 'is defined'.

Comment: @rup I agree the answers there pretty wack, I didnt understand half of them answers and their technical B-S, they should be more friendly with their answer and not assume everyone is on their level :) especially when someone asks :)

Comment: The title of this question is much easier to find then the duplicate one

Answer (score 12, accepted):

i believe it is used for enforcing boolean types...

for example

```
if("true" == true){
    alert("1");
}else{
    if(!!"true" == true){
        alert("2");
    }
}
```

alerts 2 not 1

Comment: This is horri-bad. Try `if(!!"false" == true) { alert("false"); }` and see what happens.

Comment: I did not say you should use it

Answer (score 5):

I think it used to [not so] implicitly cast value to boolean type